# CursorAdapter's newView function not get fired

Tags: android, video, cursor, android-cursoradapter

I am having trouble firing the newView function when using the CursorAdapter

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_local_screen,
            container, false);


    Bundle data = new Bundle();
    data.putStringArray("PROJECTION", new String [] { 
        MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns._ID,
        MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME, 
        MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.BUCKET_ID,
        MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATE_TAKEN,
        MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATE_ADDED,
        MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DESCRIPTION,
        MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DURATION});

    data.putString("SELECTION", null);
    data.putStringArray("SELECTIONARRAY", null);
    data.putString("SORTORDER", MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME + " LIMIT " + mLimit);

    VideoCursorAdapter adapter = new VideoCursorAdapter(getActivity(),null,true);
    LocalVideos videos = new LocalVideos(getActivity(), adapter);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(LocalVideos.LoaderID.THUMBNAIL.getID(), data, videos);

    ListView listView = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listVideos);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    videos.setView(listView);
```

Above code I setting the argument for loading the mediastore data. Setting the listView with the videoCursorAdapter.

In a LoadVideos, I have a cursor loader to load the cursor and pass it to the cursor loader.

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (LoaderID.THUMBNAIL.getID() == arg0) 
        return new CursorLoader(mContext, 
                                MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
                                (String[])arg1.getStringArray("PROJECTION"), 
                                arg1.getString("SELECTION"), 
                                (String[])arg1.getStringArray("SELECTIONARRAY"), 
                                arg1.getString("SORTORDER"));
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.w("ALBUM", "id="+arg0.getId() + " " + LoaderID.THUMBNAIL.getID() + " " + arg1.getCount());
    if (LoaderID.THUMBNAIL.getID() == arg0.getId())
        mAdapter.swapCursor(arg1); 
    mView.invalidate();
}
```

The code does print 10 data in the cursor. Somehow there is no error. But the newView function didn't get hit.

Comment: Have you check that all of the THUMBNAIL.getID() get the same value?

Comment: I have checked that the Thumbnail.getID and arg0.getID are the same. The swapCursor did get called.

Answer (score 0):

newView is not always been hit, the adapter only call newView() when necessary. (e.g. the item in list is increase after swap the cursor)
(If you have experience of implementing BaseAdapter, you can think that the convertView only been construct when it is null)
You can check [the source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/widget/CursorAdapter.java#L243) of CursorAdapter to confirm.

Comment: VideoCursorAdapter adapter = new VideoCursorAdapter(getActivity(),null,true); I have a code initialize the VideoCursorAdapter where it set the cursor to null. Then I used a swapCursor to swap from null to a new cursor.

Comment: How do i check that? i only need to implement newView and bindView

Comment: So your VideoCursorAdapter extends from CursorAdapter, and your newView() function never been called??

Comment: Yes. u are right. I tried to assign the adapter to the listview after swapCursor but still no luck

Comment: I think the code you pasted is correct. Does your VideoCursorAdapter overwrite any function except newView()/bindView()?

Comment: If you catch any exception in logcat, paste it is helpful.

Comment: Hmm i just realized I have a problem with viewPager , it didnt show the fragment inside the viewpager.

Comment: You mean that your listview never show? hmm... well, it is a good news.

Comment: Yes I found the problem. I should have use the getChildFragmentManager instead of getFragmentManager.